# Mostrar un fragmento separado de la grafica pastel

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

Buen día para todos

Estoy realizando una grafica de unos datos pero quiero que el dato en La grafica con mayor porcentaje este separado de los demás como en este ejemplo
[image: Ejemplo]

al momento de realizarlo creo que lo estoy haciendo mal porque me muestra error

error:
`TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'explode'`

mi código es este:

```
valorx=df_palabras["Palabra"]
valory=df_palabras["Frecuencia"]
    
    
#grafica
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6)) #definimos el tamaño del cuadro
labels=valorx #obtenemos los labels
explode = (0, 0.1, 0, 0)
plt.pie(valory, autopct='%1.2f%%', labels=valorx) #graficamos
plt.legend(labels, bbox_to_anchor =(1, 1),title="Palabras",explode=explode,) #especificamos la leyenda
plt.title('Frecuencia de palabras')#ponemos un titulo para la grafica
plt.show()
```

mi salida:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Nota**

la cantidad de datos que se muestra no es siempre el mismo se limita a la cantidad que el usuario ingrese

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

El problema está en tu `explode`, este debe ser un arreglo del mismo tamaño que la cantidad de datos que quieres mostrar, en tu caso estás mostrando 10 elementos y en tu `explode` solo defines 4 elementos

Puedes solucionarlo si usas el siguiente código donde estás creando la gráfica:

```
plt.pie(valory, autopct='%1.2f%%', labels=valorx, explode=(valory == max(valory)) * 0.1)
```

Explicación:

La línea `(valory == max(valory))` va a crear un arreglo de booleanos en el que únicamente será `True` en la posición del valor máximo de tu serie `valory`. Supongamos que tiene 6 elementos y que el penúltimo es el máximo.

```
array([False, False, False, False, True, False])
```

Luego, al multiplicar por un factor para la "explosión" (Por ejemplo 0.1) va a resultar un arreglo como el siguiente:

```
array([0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0.1 , 0.])
```

Comment: Muchas gracias comprendí mi problema y entendí la solución que me diste y de igual manera me funciono. Muchas gracias